# Does the Yellow Squad's Move + Activate card swap places with a space marine or move and then shift the formation?

Tags: death-angel

The text for the Move + Activate action for the Yellow Squad reads,

> Your Space Marines may move to any position in the formation (instead of just to adjacent positions).

I'm just not sure whether to shift the formation after moving the space marine or to swap positions with the space marine that already holds the target position.

When the rules explain the normal movement of space maring into adjacent positions, the text reads,

> To move a Space Marine to an adjacent position, he simply picks up the Space Marine card, and switches its position with any adjacent Space Marine.

Based on that text in the rule book, I've been making the assumption that swapping positions is also what was intended for the Yellow Squad. Is that correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to Page 28 of the [Official Rules](http://www.fantasyflightgames.com/ffg_content/death-angel/minisite/support/death-angel-rulebook-web.pdf):

> If a Space Marine is ever able to move to a non-adjacent position
>   (with a card or ability), he does not cause the formation to shift. He
>   simply switches places with the Space Marine that occupied his new
>   position.

Comment: Nice catch. Can't get much more explicit than that.

Answer (score 2):

Your assumption makes sense to me.  The action lets you move to *any* rather than an *adjacent* position, but otherwise follows all of the usual rules for movement.  That's certainly how we play it.

(The only viable alternative rule to shuffle each marine moved pass one space down the formation, until the vacated space is filled, but that would cause a lot more movement of marines than the rules to this game usually intend.)